# run script inside ksh shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am trying to execute a script ksh that reads a file and execute other script to access the MySQL database. But the second script doesn't return any result. Does anyone know why? please.

```
#!/bin/ksh

vet=($(cat lasts_tasks.txt))
echo ${vet[@]}

for workunit in ${vet[@]};
do
        echo "workunit:$workunit"
        exe="/var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult $workunit;"
        echo ""$exe
        result=`$exe`
        echo $result
done
```

The results are:

```
# ./lerArquivo.sh 
m52cc_job_5 m52cc_job_6 m52cc_job_7
workunit:m52cc_job_5
/var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult m52cc_job_5;

workunit:m52cc_job_6
/var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult m52cc_job_6;

workunit:m52cc_job_7
/var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult m52cc_job_7;
```

But when I execute the lines alone, I have the right result:

```
# /var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult m52cc_job_7;
105
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `;` in your command is interpretted as a literal semicolon, so you're basically running

```
/var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult m52cc_job_6\; ;
```

Just remove the semicolon from your `exe` variable:

```
#!/bin/ksh

vet=($(cat lasts_tasks.txt))
echo ${vet[@]}

for workunit in ${vet[@]};
do
        echo "workunit:$workunit"
        exe="/var/www/boinc/m52cc/query_tasks.sh m52cc -workunitResult $workunit"
        echo ""$exe
        result=`$exe`
        echo $result
done
```